# How does weak convergence implies strong convergence in the setting of compact inclusion?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces

The following hand-waving argument is in the proof of Lemma 8.4 in Constantin and Foias's *Navier-Stokes Equations*:

> Suppose $X,Y,Z$ are Hilbert spaces such that we have the following embedding properties
>   $$
> X\overset{\text{cpt}}{\hookrightarrow}Y\hookrightarrow Z.
> $$
>   ($X$ is compactly embedded in $Y$, and $Y$ is continuously embedded in $Z$.)
>
> Suppose $x_n\to 0$ weakly in $X$. Then $x_n$ convergens strongly in $Y$ and *a fortiori* in $Z$.

Would anyone explain why this is true (or I misses something that this argument needs more assumptions)? What does "*a fortiori*" mean here?

Comment: To answer the last question, *a fortiori* can be understood as *thus necessarily* or *hence certainly*.

Comment: Should it be *strongly* in $Y$?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis: yes, thanks!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks for you comment! Maybe I should put a `topology` tag to this question I think?

Comment: @Jack: That should be okay, yes.